# `dotnet watch` does not detect changes

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-core

I run `dotnet watch --project Me.Myproject.csproj run` within a container in a local kubernetes cluster with a volume mount, but changes are not detected.

If I run the same command locally, the changes are detected. If I restart the pod (without rebuilding the container), the changes are included.

The project itself is pretty much the boilerplate gRPC template:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.27.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My environmental variables:

```
- DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
```

They don't seem to have any effect on the watcher.